# How can a program run faster with an odd number of threads than with even number?

Tags: performance, openmp, multicore, matrix-multiplication

For my OpenMP compute intensive application, where each thread performs the same number (1600) of matrix multiplications, and where each thread is executed by a separate core, I am finding that odd number of threads perform little better (in terms of giga floating point operations per second per thread) than an even number of threads. The processor is 12 core AMD Opteron 6168. Has anyone else seen such behavior? The attached graph shows this:

[image: graph 1]

> Throughput per core when the number of matrix multiplications is increased as
>   1600 times the number of CPU cores. Matrix size is 16x16x16

Comment: Could this be an artifact of how the calculations are done? (e.g. an error computing the average)

Comment: I think you are right. Though there was no error in averaging over the cores, but when I tried with a different load, I didn't get the same pattern. So I think I will put the issue to rest. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok, that's a K10 microarchitecture CPU, quite old.  The Bulldozer-family has pairs of cores, but in K10 each core has its own L1 cache.  K10 has 64kiB L1D cache, so that's big enough to hold the whole matrix: 16^3 * 8B = 32kiB.  Does the number of threads affect the addresses of the memory used for the arrays?  Agner Fog's microarch docs say K10 suffers from cache-bank conflicts (within a single thread in a single core, cutting down from 2 memory ops per clock to one.)  To get a better theory, you'd need performance-counter numbers that show a difference in some counter.